# How to avoid function overlaps while using Array (Bounce game)?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm writing a collision function to help the object stop moving in a certain direction when facing a block/wall. But it seems that the function has been overlapped because I have called this function multiple times in the draw function of the javascript. How do I prevent this from happening if I want to draw an entire level for the game? For reference, I'm recreating the Bounce game on Nokia.

```js
let cX = 150, cY = 250, size = 50;  // circle
let velY = 0;
let gravity = 0.3;

let blockX = new Array (999);
let blockY = new Array (999);

function draw() {
  background(230);
  
  velY += gravity;  // ball falls faster with time
  cY += velY;

  if (cX - size/2 < 0)  // ball touches left wall
    {
      cX = 0 + size/2;
    }
  if (cX + size/2 > width)  // ball touches right wall
    {
      cX = width - size/2;
    }
  
  // creates object
  for (i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
      blockX[i] = size * i;
      blockY[i] = size * 7;
      square(blockX[i], blockY[i], size);
      collision();
    }
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
      blockX[i] = size * 7;
      blockY[i] = size * (i+3);
      square(blockX[i], blockY[i], size);
      collision();
    }
  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
      blockX[i] = 0;
      blockY[i] = size * (i+1);
      square(blockX[i], blockY[i], size);
      collision();
    }
  
  if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW))    // move left
    {
      cX += -3;
    }
  if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW))   // move right
    {
      cX += 3;
    }
  if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW) && cY + size/2 == blockY[i])  // ball touches ground
    {
      velY = -12;
    }
}

function collision()
{
  if (cY + size/2 > blockY[i] && cY < blockY[i] && blockX[i]-5 <= cX && cX <= blockX[i]+5 + size)  // ball touches top of block
    {
      cY = blockY[i] - size/2;
      velY = -0.4 * velY;
    }
  if (cX - size/2 < blockX[i] + size && cX - size/2 > blockX[i] + size/2 && blockY[i] <= cY && cY <= blockY[i] + size)  // ball touches right of block
    {
      cX = blockX[i] + size * 3/2;
    }
  if (cY - size/2 < blockY[i] + size && cY > blockY[i] + size/2 && blockX[i]-5 <= cX && cX <= blockX[i]+5 + size)  // ball touches bottom of block
    {
      cY = blockY[i] + size * 3/2;
    }
  if (cX + size/2 > blockX[i] && cX + size/2 < blockX[i] + size/2 && blockY[i] <= cY && cY <= blockY[i] + size)  // ball touches left of block
    {
      cX = blockX[i] - size/2;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

The occurring problem is that the ball can't jump if it's standing on a higher block than the floor.

Comment: The `draw()` function is called on each frame, so yes, obviously you'll see it being called all the time. As long as you're not doing any async operations, you don't have to worry that functions will "overlap". Javascript is synchronous by default, so it'll just run one task after another. Your problem is most likely with the `if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW) && cY + size/2 == blockY[i])` statement. It's probably returning false, hence the jump doesn't take place. Put a `console.log()` in there to see if it's being triggered or not. If not, up to you to find out why

Comment: So i did do that, returning console.log(blockY[i]) and it turns out that the value is stuck at the floor. I think it's because blockY[i] can't be called outside the loop hence it sticks to a certain value or undefined.

Comment: True, you can't use the variable `i` outside of its loop. The loop is what declares that variable. Once the loop is finished or outside of the loop, that variable no longer exists or isn't available to you. However, what you _can_ do is pass the `i` variable as a parameter to the `collision()` method. Since `i` does exist inside the loop, that will work fine. Just do `collision(i);` inside the loop. Change `function collision()` to `function collision(i)` and you're good to go.